# Issues with an event trigger in unity

Tags: unity, 2d

I am working on a 2D platformer and I am trying to do a character selection menu. I have and button with an event trigger that I use for shooting for the character. My problem is that when I switch to a new character the event trigger that is on the button goes blank and I can no longer shoot. I have tried instantiating the characters and having the SetActive to false. Is there a way to set the event trigger through code or if anybody has any other suggestions I would love to hear them.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood of your issue, you need to dinamically change the Button's [onClick](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) property when a character is switched, right? So you need to get access to either that button or its onClick property (which is of type **ButtonClickedEvent**) and use **RemoveAllListeners** to remove any method assigned of previous characters, and then use **AddListener** to add the method of a new character.

AddListener receives an **UnityAction** which is a delegate of a parameterless void Method's signature, so you need to pass a pointer to a method of that signature. Example:

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button eventButton;

    public void OnCharacterChange()
    {
        eventButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        eventButton.onClick.AddListener(ButtonEvent);
    }

    void ButtonEvent()
    {
        //...
    }

    void ButtonEventWithParams(string args)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Now, if you would like to add a listener of a method with parameters, you'd need to make a UnityAction's signature method that calls that method with parameter, for you to avoid a creation of that intermediate method, you can either use [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions), or do a delegate encapsulation (I think that's the way of calling it, it may be wrong). A quick example:

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button eventButton;

    public void OnCharacterChange()
    {
        eventButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        //eventButton.onClick.AddListener(ButtonEvent);

        /// With Lambda Expressions:
        eventButton.onClick.AddListener(=>{ ButtonEventWithParams("Hello"); });

        /// With delegate encapsulation:
        eventButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate{ ButtonEventWithParams("Hello"); });
    }

    void ButtonEvent()
    {
        //...
    }

    void ButtonEventWithParams(string arg)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

You can check more reference on [ButtonClickedEvent's API.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.ButtonClickedEvent.html) Hope it helps.